# Can you use floating point numbers or math in the Runtime?

Tags: balances, percent, fixed-point-math, float, floating-point-math

I would like to do some basic operations in the runtime like:

```
let new_balance = .5 * old_balance;
```

Or save a percentage value in the runtime storage.

Or represent the balance of a user like: `3.141592 TOKENS`

How can I do these kinds of things? Am I allowed to use floating point numbers in the runtime?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot use floating point math inside of the runtime.

[Floating point numbers](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0) can lead to non-determinism in computer systems, and that would be exceptionally bad for blockchains since all of them must come to consensus.

Instead, you must make sure to use [fixed-point arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) within the entire runtime environment, and Substrate even provides tools to help you with this in the crate [`sp_arithmetic`](https://crates.parity.io/sp_arithmetic/index.html).

So to answer these specific scenarios:

- Consider dividing by 2 rather than multiplying by .5.

```
let new_balance = old_balance / 2;
```

- Use the [`Percent`](https://crates.parity.io/sp_arithmetic/per_things/struct.Percent.html) type or some of the other [`per_thing` types](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/129/what-is-perbill-and-where-should-it-be-used) which behave like a standard percentage, but use fixed point math under the covers.
- Use a fixed point number.

In Substrate, user balances are normally represented with a `u128`. However, to express these balances in "human form" a fixed point decimal is used. So while a user's real balance as a `u128` would be something like `3_141_592_000_000 UNITS`, we would represent it in the UI by first dividing by `10^12`, and displaying it as `3.141592 TOKENS`. Assuming your fixed point decimal is 12. However different networks may make different choices how many decimal places to use.

This decision is arbitrary.

Comment: Is it possible to use `sp_arithmetic` in ink contracts?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, `sp-arithmetic` can not fit your requirement.

Please also take a look at the [substrate-fixed](https://github.com/encointer/substrate-fixed).