# Rust ink. Division wont return a number with float point

Tags: ink, rust, floating-point-math

I'm trying to calculate a value of token by using division operator,
it will return a number higher then 1, but never returns
here is the code of the price calculation:

```
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn get_price_for_token_a_as_input(&self) -> Balance {

            let pool_b_amount: Balance = self.token_b.balance_of(self.get_account_id());
           

            let opr:Balance = 10;
            let one = 1*opr.pow(12);


            let price_from_one_token_a_to_b = one (1) / pool_b_amount (200);
            
            

            price_from_one_token_a_to_b
        }
```

The Value of  `price_from_one_token_a_to_b` is always 0.

the values are already 10^12.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the value of `pool_b_amount`? What is the expected number you want to get given that value?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi Hey, i updated the question, thank you for your time sir.

Comment: You should try [printing](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/blob/0d2cc5b49ea40cdd2875604149d0c11767ef1236/examples/contract-transfer/lib.rs#L33) the balance of `pool_b_amount` to make sure it is `200` and not `200e12`.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @forgetso.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions.html#expression-precedence be careful, I don't think your `price_from_one_token_a_to_b` is acting as expected with order of operations

Comment: see also: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/146/can-you-use-floating-point-numbers-or-math-in-the-runtime

Comment: @forgetso is correct.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot use floating point maths in `ink!`. If you do something like `10/7` then you will get `1` as a result (rounded from `1.42857142857`).

It looks like you're calculating `1e12/200e12` which is `0.005` and therefore rounded to `0`. `1e12/200` is `5e9` and is perhaps what you expected based on your code comments.

Check out [this answer](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/147/380) for a more complete explanation of why floating point maths is excluded.