# Scale codec f64 support

Tags: scale-codec, scale

What is the reason that the SCALE codec does not support Encode and Decode of f64 types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically this question boils down to: [Can you use floating point numbers or math in the Runtime?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/146/can-you-use-floating-point-numbers-or-math-in-the-runtime)

While SCALE could deterministically encode and decode floating point types, the runtime can't deterministically do compute on them. Interestingly to do some benchmarks of SCALE f64/f32 support was hacked in to allow like for like comparison of serialisation benchmarks: https://github.com/paritytech/parity-scale-codec/issues/341