# How can I calculate natural log of a number?

Tags: fixed-point-math, floating-point-math, float

Floating-point arithmetic are [not allowed in substrate runtime](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/147/213).

[f64](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html#method.ln) has an `pub fn ln(self) -> f64` to calculate natural log. How can I do that in substrate without using floating points.

Comment: You can work with different representation of numbers. For example after getting an answer like 2.5 you do 2.5 * 10 and in the front end you can divide back.

Comment: In what context do you want to use this? What base specifically do you need? Perhaps `e` also know as natural? What accuracy do you need in the result and why?

Comment: Was thinking of logarithmic inflation of tokens. 4 to 5 decimal accuracy would be fine.