How to Use sin() and cos() in ink! Smart Contracts?
I'm working on a smart contract using the ink! framework for Polkadot, and I need to perform some trigonometric calculations, specifically using the sin() and cos() functions. Since ink! is based on Rust, I understand I can use Rust's standard math library, but I have some questions about the best way to do this.
    pub fn calculate_distance(lat1: f64, lon1: f64, lat2: f64, lon2: f64) -> f64 {
        let r = 6371000.0; // Radius of the Earth in meters
        let d_lat = to_radian((lat2 - lat1) as f64);
        let d_lon = to_radian((lon2 - lon1) as f64);

        let a = (d_lat / 2.0).sin() * (d_lat / 2.0).sin()
            + to_radian(lat1 as f64).cos()
                * to_radian(lat2 as f64).cos()
                * (d_lon / 2.0).sin()
                * (d_lon / 2.0).sin();

        let c = 2.0 * a.sqrt().atan2((1.0 - a).sqrt());

        r * c
    }

i get the following error message while compiling the ink! contract

error[E0599]: no method named `cos` found for type `f64` in the current scope
  --> /Users/dave/Work/match-contract-polkadot/lib.rs:50:38
   |
50 |             + to_radian(lat1 as f64).cos()
   |                                      ^^^ method not found in `f64`

error[E0599]: no method named `cos` found for type `f64` in the current scope
  --> /Users/dave/Work/match-contract-polkadot/lib.rs:51:42
   |
51 |                 * to_radian(lat2 as f64).cos()
   |                                          ^^^ method not found in `f64`

error[E0599]: no method named `sin` found for type `f64` in the current scope
   --> /Users/dave/Work/match-contract-polkadot/lib.rs:52:33
    |
52  |                 * (d_lon / 2.0).sin()
    |                                 ^^^
    |
help: there is a method `min` with a similar name, but with different arguments
   --> /Users/dave/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/num/f64.rs:963:5
    |
963 |     pub fn min(self, other: f64) -> f64 {
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0599]: no method named `sin` found for type `f64` in the current scope
   --> /Users/dave/Work/match-contract-polkadot/lib.rs:53:33
    |
53  |                 * (d_lon / 2.0).sin();
    |                                 ^^^
    |
help: there is a method `min` with a similar name, but with different arguments
   --> /Users/dave/.rustup/toolchains/stable-aarch64-apple-darwin/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/num/f64.rs:963:5
    |
963 |     pub fn min(self, other: f64) -> f64 {
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error[E0599]: no method named `sqrt` found for type `{float}` in the current scope
  --> /Users/dave/Work/match-contract-polkadot/lib.rs:55:48
   |
55 |         let c = 2.0 * a.sqrt().atan2((1.0 - a).sqrt());

Questions:

Is there any concern with using floating-point numbers in ink! contracts, specifically for trigonometric functions like sin() and cos()?
Would it be better to implement fixed-point math instead of using f64 for more precision and gas efficiency?
Are there any best practices for handling math operations like these in smart contracts on Polkadot?
Thanks for the help!


As for floating numbers: ink! docs and another answer: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/146/can-you-use-floating-point-numbers-or-math-in-the-runtime
